# is there a way to run any exec family function as a thread in c

Tags: c, multithreading, process, pthreads, exec

I think the question is self-explanatory.

I know exec runs on another process, so if I wanted to ls a directory I would do something like that.

```
int pid;
if((pid = fork()) != -1) {
     if(!pid) {
         execl("/bin/ls", "-a", "-l", (char *) 0);
     } else {
         wait(&status);
     }
} else //error
```

That's fine if you want to create a process, but what about threads?. I though firs to create the thread and then the exec function but that would make the thread I just created have two process

Answer (score 7):

This wouldn't make sense.  Threads share the same address space as each other (which includes program code); it wouldn't be possible for two separate executables to co-exist in the same process, as they'd simply destroy each other.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible, `exec` will simply replace the current process with the specified executable, so your original process no longer exists. Also, a process is a higher unit of execution than a thread, so it doesn't make sense to "run a process inside another thread".

Comment: +1 for 'size' hierarchy - its like saying you want to build a house in your bathroom, or a car in your engine...

Comment: Good points but, being the anal-retentive nitpicker that I am :-), I'd like to point out that `exec` doesn't replace the current process, it replaces the current _program_ in the process. The original _process_ still exists, it's just had a new _program_ loaded into it.

Answer (score 4):

You should step back and tell us the *real* requirements. You should be asking how to achieve what you want, not how to achieve it in a specific way. By doing the latter, you limit the possibilities, which is rarely wise.

For what it's worth, that code will work under POSIX, as only the calling thread is suspended until the child finishes.

If you want the subprocess to run as a thread in the current process, that's not going to work. You're trying to intermix two different abstraction levels and, the instant you `exec`, the current process has an *entire* new program loaded into it. That won't affect the parent (since you forked) but you can't run `ls` (or any other program) in a thread of an *existing* process.

---

Based on your comments:

> `... because my main process has a lot of variables and stuff and I didn't want to duplicate that memory space because of the fork.`

Modern operating systems *won't* duplicate everything on a `fork`, they're rather smarter than that.

Linux, for example, will only copy page tables and create a new task structure. All other memory is marked copy-on-write so it can be split *only when needed.*

In addition, Linux has a `vfork` that won't even duplicate the page tables, at least until you call `exec` but the parent is suspended until that point (or `_exit`) to prevent cross-process corruption, and you're very limited in what the child is allowed to do.

Comment: That was an example code, I just wanted to know if was possible to run exec as thread, mainly because my main process has a lot of variables and stuff and I didn't want to duplicate that memory space because of the fork, that's all. I guessed I didn't read the theory well through to know that exec IS to execute another process

Comment: `wait()` does *not* cause the entire parent process to pause until the child has finished - only the thread that calls `wait()`.  The [POSIX spec for `wait()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/waitpid.html) says *"The wait() function shall suspend execution of the calling **thread** until..."*

Comment: Apologies, @caf, you're absolutely right. Removed that bit from the answer and updated to cover fork/exec behaviour as well.

Comment: It's a shame this question isn't marked as answered... your answer seems pretty complete to me.

Answer (score 2):

> When any thread calls one of the exec() functions, the calling program is completely replaced. All threads, except the one that called exec(), vanish immediately. None of the threads executes destructors for thread-specific data or calls cleanup handlers. All of the (process-private) mutexes and condition variables belonging to the process also disappear. After an exec(), the thread ID of the remaining thread is unspecified.
>                                            Michael KerrisK "The Linux Programming Interface"